# copy and paste an entire layout in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have an inner constraint layout that is hosting an icon, text and button to open another activity.
This is the XML

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/manageMyAccount"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/settings_manage_my_account"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Manage My Account" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrowforward" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I need about 40 instances like this with different text and Icons, other than make it a list(which I can't as I have 2 types of those layouts. how can I effectively copy and pate this without creating name conflict? and the other mess that comes with it.

Comment: What about creating custom view or fragment for this?

Comment: **Which I can't as I have 2 types of those layouts** what do you mean by that?

Comment: I've created it, but how do I "export" it and make it visible in the palette?

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad I have two types of layouts, and I need to put them in a spesific order (5 normal 1 unique then 12 normal 1 unique....and so on. so creating it by code seems redundant.

Comment: @TomAbarba then why you don't use `RecyclerView` with different `ViewHolders`?

Comment: You can [re-use layouts with <include/>](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts) to merge your basic layouts into a bigger one.